# Imprimir letras que estão fora do collections.Counter

Tags: python, python-3.x

Fiz um código que retorna a recorrência de caracteres de um arquivo.

```
from collections import Counter

with open('hino.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    conteudo = f.read()
    counter = Counter(conteudo)
    print(counter)
```

E essa foi a saída dele:

```
Counter({' ': 138, 'e': 97, 'a': 87, 'o': 80, 'r': 65, 's': 54, 'd': 42, '\n': 38, 'i': 31, 't': 31, 'n': 28, 'm': 28, 'l': 27, 'u': 27, ',': 20, 'p': 15, 'b': 13, 'v': 10, 'c': 9, 'f': 8, 'E': 8, 'í': 6, 'z': 6, '!': 6, 'B': 6, 'ç': 5, 'S': 4, 'g': 4, 'P': 4, 'R': 4, 'q': 4, 'j': 4, 'Q': 4, 'D': 4, 'ã': 3, 'A': 3, '.': 3, 'C': 3, 'h': 3, 'á': 2, 'N': 2, 'T': 1, 'à': 1, 'é': 1, ';': 1, 'J': 1})
```

Como eu faria para imprimir também as letras que não possuem constam no resultado do Counter?

Por exemplo:

```
Y:0
```

Outra questão, como eu poderia fazer para imprimir o número de espaços e a letra com maior incidência?

Que seria o `' ':138 e 'e': 97`

Answer (score 1):

[Segundo a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), um `Counter` é uma subclasse de `dict`, e portanto também é um dicionário. Por isso é possível verificar se um elemento existe e obtê-lo, da mesma forma que fazemos com dicionários.

---

Para obter as letras que não estão no `Counter`, basta verificar se elas são chaves do dicionário. Uma opção é usar `in`:

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter()
with open('hino.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    for linha in f:
        counter.update(linha)

from string import ascii_letters

acentos = 'áéíóúãõâêîôûç'
todas_letras = ascii_letters + acentos + acentos.upper()

for letra in todas_letras:
    if letra not in counter:
        print(f'{letra}: 0')
```

Mudei um pouco a forma de ler o arquivo. Claro que usar `read()` também funciona, mas este método carrega todo o conteúdo do arquivo para a memória. Se o arquivo for pequeno não faz diferença, mas para arquivos maiores, pode ser interessante lê-lo linha a linha para não gastar memória à toa (e o `for linha in f` faz isso, lê o arquivo uma linha por vez e logo em seguida a descarta, em vez de carregar o arquivo inteiro de uma vez).

Depois eu criei uma string contendo todas as letras. Como o seu `Counter` está diferenciando letras maiúsculas, minúsculas e acentuadas, estou assumindo que `A`, `a`, `á`, `Á`, `ã`, `Ã`, etc, são letras diferentes. Se quer uma definição diferente, basta mudar a string `todas_letras` para ter apenas o que você precisar.

Depois eu faço um *loop* pelas letras e só imprimo as que não estão no `Counter`.

Outra opção é usar [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-set):

```
counter = ... # cria o Counter

from string import ascii_letters

acentos = 'áéíóúãõâêîôûç'
todas_letras = set(ascii_letters + acentos + acentos.upper())

for letra in sorted(todas_letras - set(counter.keys())):
    print(f'{letra}: 0')
```

Primeiro eu crio um `set` com todas as letras, e subtraio de outro `set` contendo apenas as chaves do `Counter`. O resultado é outro `set`, contendo as letras que não estão no `Counter`. Eu uso `sorted` para retornar as letras em ordem alfabética, já que um `set` não garante a ordem dos elementos (lembrando que as letras acentuadas ficarão no final, mas uma vez tendo as letras, você pode mostrar da forma que quiser).

---

Se quer mostrar quantas vezes um determinado caractere ocorre, basta usá-lo como chave. Por exemplo, para o espaço:

```
# imprime quantas vezes o espaço ocorreu
print(counter[' '])
```

Já para a letra mais frequente, você tem que obter os elementos mais frequentes com [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common), e percorrê-los até encontrar uma letra:

```
# busca a letra mais frequente
for c, qtd in counter.most_common():
    if c.isalpha(): # encontrei uma letra
        print(f'Letra {c} ocorre {qtd} vezes')
        break # se já encontrei, interrompo o loop
```

Fiz assim porque não sei como está o seu texto, e vai que os caracteres mais frequentes não são letras (podem ser espaço, sinais de pontuação, números, etc). Então eu prefiro percorrer os caracteres mais comuns até encontrar uma letra. E quando encontro, interrompo o *loop* com `break`.

Mas isso só mostra uma letra. E se tiver empate? Nesse caso, você pode pegar a letra mais frequente, e imprimir todas que têm a mesma quantidade:

```
letras = list(filter(lambda c: c[0].isalpha(), counter.most_common()))
maior_qtd = letras[0][1]
print(f'Letras mais comuns, ocorrem {maior_qtd} vezes')
for c, qtd in letras:
    if qtd != maior_qtd:
        break # não é a mais frequente, interrompe o loop
    print(c)
```

Primeiro eu uso [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) para gerar uma lista contendo somente as letras do `Counter` (e suas respectivas quantidades). Depois pego a quantidade do primeiro elemento (ou seja, da letra mais frequente).

Em seguida, eu percorro a lista e vejo se as letras ocorrem na mesma quantidade de vezes da mais frequente. Quando tiver um valor diferente, eu interrompo o *loop*.

Assim, se duas ou mais letras forem a mais frequente, todas elas serão mostradas.

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
from collections import Counter
```

Pegando os caracteres ascii

```
asciiLetters = string.ascii_letters
```

Criando um dicionário com chave(letra) e com o valor(0)

```
dicionario = {key:0 for (key) in asciiLetters}
```

Abrindo o arquivo e contando as ocorrências das letras

```
with open('hino.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    counter = Counter(f.read())
```

Atualizando o dicionário com os valores que Counter contou

```
dicionario.update(dict(counter))
dicionario
```

Aqui mostra os caracteres com maior ocorrência

```
counter.most_common()[:3]
```

---

Código

```
import string
from collections import Counter

asciiLetters = string.ascii_letters
dicionario = {key:0 for (key) in asciiLetters}

with open('hino.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    counter = Counter(f.read())

dicionario.update(dict(counter))
dicionario

counter.most_common()[:3]
```